# Checking whether a popover exists or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap popover. I have a page that may contain some popover. Now I'm displaying the popover like this -

```
target = $('#' + currentPopoverId.data('next-popover-id'));
target.popover('show');
```

But the problem is in my current page the `target` may not exist all time. So how can I check if `target` exists or not? I've tried -

```
target.length
```

but it always gives 1 if whether it exists or not.

Comment: reset your target variable everytime your page loads target  = ' ';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there is target and any content(children) inside the target(popover)

```
if(target.is(":visible") && target.children().length >1){
 //content present inside popover
 }
```